# HFSS - Replacing a variable with a new variable

Tags: variable

I want to put two similar designs in a single design. Both designs share some common variables with different values. When I put them together in a single design the common variables share same values and thus destroy the designs.

So my question is if there is any process/script which can allow me to replace a certain variable with a new variable?

Comment: show your schematic. Circuits are not pure-math, not pure algebra..

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, an HFSS design doesn't necessarily have schematics.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, I have two similar designs, .e.g. D1 ad D2. In D1, I have variabes with x=1, p=1, r=5 and in D2 I have variabes with x=2, q=1, z=7.

I would like to make third design, which will include both D1 and D2 with their respective values of the variables. But in HFSS, when D1 and D2 are put together, it takes a single value for a common variable (variable x in this case). This is reasonable.

So for me, it would have been helpful, if I can replace the name of variable x with e.g x1 in all the coponents using this variable D1 or in D2. Then this conflict would have been resolved.